# Test posting data to a web server that requires authentication

Tags: java, authentication

I need to test my code that posts data to a web page that requires authentication (BASIC/DIGEST/etc). I am wondering if there's an existing open source project that I can quickly deploy and test my code against.

Answer (score 0):

[Apache HttpComponentsClient](http://hc.apache.org/) could meet your requirements.